# how can i do opacity transitions in vertical slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slider, slick.js

I want to make a vertical text slider for my website.
i want to do it opacity transitions like this: https://ibb.co/XVYd7hH

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="group" type="radio"  name="rb" value='4.90' onclick="add_delivery_cost(this.value)" />
             
       <input class="group1" type="checkbox" value='13.95' name="rb" id="total" onclick="add_delivery_cost(this.value)" />
    
       <input class="group2" type="radio" name="rb"  value='5.90' onclick="add_delivery_cost(this.value)" />
     
       <input class="group3" type="radio"   ng-model='mValue' value="" checked="checked"/>

       <div class="container">
         <div class="div24">Междинна сума:</div>
         <div class="div25">27.90лв</div>
         <div class="div26">4.90лв</div>
         <div class="div27">Общо:</div>
         <div class="div28">Информация</div>
         <div class="frame-child12"></div>
         <div class="frame-child13"></div>
         <div class="frame-child14"></div>
         <img class="removal-3-icon" alt="" src="./public/removal-3@2x.png" />

         <div class="div29">
           <p class="p"> тест</p>
           <p class="p">Над 400 числа</p>
           <p class="p">друг тест,</p>
           <p class="p">много</p>
           <p class="p">други.</p>
         </div>
         <div class="div30">68.00 лв.</div>
         <div class="div31">72.90 лв.</div>
         <div class="div32">27.90лв.</div>
         <div class="div33" id="total-price-td">27.90лв.</div>
         <input type="hidden" id="total-price" value="27.90">
         
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script>
     var price_string=$('#total-price').val();
     function add_delivery_cost(val){
     
         var delivery_cost=parseFloat(val);//Converting to float value//Returns  24.00
         var price=parseFloat(price_string);//Converting to float value
         var total_price=(price+delivery_cost).toFixed(2);//Adding delivery cost to price and rounding to 2 decimal points
         var price_html=''+total_price;
         $('#total-price-td').html(price_html);//Updating the `html` content of total-price with a new value after adding delivery cost to the price.
     }
 </script>
```

how can i do opacity transitions?